# Why clicking in a report on a textbox garbages results?

Tags: ms-access, report, vba

Can anyone help, I don't know what's happening.

For the table that looks like this:

```
part  value   
BAC    102  
BS1    275  
MAV    425  
BAC    519  
BSF    653  
BAC   1072
```

The result would be:
For part BAC

```
part  value  difference   
BAC    102       102  
BAC    519       417  
BAC   1072       553
```

There aren't any relations except value is in order.

A modified function of @Tom Collins was used:

```
Function GetDiff(CurrPart As String, CurrValue As Long) As Long  
Static LastPart As String  
Static LastValue As Long  
   If CurrPart <> LastPart Then  
      LastValue = 0  
      LastPart = CurrPart  
   End If  
   If LastValue = CurrValue Then  
   GetDiff = CurrValue  
   Else  
   GetDiff = CurrValue - LastValue  
   LastValue = CurrValue  
   End If  
End Function
```

It comes out that the function works all right, but it happens a strange thing when the results are placed in a report, the first value of the query comes out wrong and when it's clicked it comes out right. Also another strange thing is, if I want an average for the field with the wrong value displayed it displays the correct average and if I click on the wrong value that turns all right the average remains the same.

Why is this happening and how it can be addressed?

Comment: You say it's in a report, then you mention clicking on it.  Are you actually outputting to a report or to a form?

Comment: @user Reports are clickable in report view. I've had weird things happen like this in my reports as well. Sometimes I have to scroll around to get results to show, and sometimes things don't show up when printed (even though their visibility and print only properties arent screwed with).

Comment: This has always been a downside of Access, and where Excel is far more useful. Having to use custom function workarounds is awkward because when you active a row on your report it will re-run the function, hence why results change on load and on click. There is a chance of writing a Ranking query which should give a more stable output.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, not quite a ranking query as I said but give this query a go:

```
SELECT part, value, difference
FROM
(SELECT A.part, A.value, (SELECT Max(B.value) FROM TableName AS B WHERE B.part = A.part AND B.value < A.value) AS offset, IIf([offset] & ""="",[value],[value]-[offset]) AS difference
FROM TableName AS A
WHERE (((A.part)="BAC"))) AS B;
```

Results:

```
part    value    difference
BAC     102      102
BAC     519      417
BAC     1072     553
```

Using a query like this rather than a dynamic function should ensure your report values do not change.

Comment: @CatalinFRANCU I have now edited my answer to give the results as per your questions example, hope it helps.